# Can't exchange widget in QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qsplitter

I have a `QSplitter` with two widgets. One of them is static, the other one is supposed to change on the press of a button. But the problem is the widget does not change.

I have a pointer for the widget that is changing: `this->content`

The widget to switch to is in the pointer named `widget`.

Here's a code snippet where I switch `widget`:

```
qDebug() << "before: " << this->content;
this->content = widget;
qDebug() << "after: " << this->content;
this->content->update();
this->content->repaint();
```

My debug output there verifies that the pointer points to the other widget:

```
before:  QLineEdit(0x363850)
after:   SCTableView(0x3644c0)
```

Trying to make it show by calling `update()` and `repaint()`, without any success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Got help from some people in #qt on freenode. Thanks.
I forgot to call setVisible(true) on this->content after switching to the new widget.